# Unable to debug in Eclipse( Mac)

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Eclipse in Mac and when I am trying to debug the application, its throwing me this error.

> ERROR: transport error 202: gethostbyname: unknown host ERROR: JDWP
>   Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510) JDWP
>   exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized
>   [debugInit.c:750]......

Even "Ping localhost"command is not fetching results. 
Googled a lot but no solution works.

Comment: Does turning the MacOS firewall off change anything?

Answer (score 1):

check /etc/host if  `127.0.0.1   localhost` is commented out

Also read [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debug/FAQ#I_can_run_a_program_but_not_debug_it.3F.3F.3F)